# How to copy database from MongoDB 1.6 instance

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB instance with two databases, let's call them "realdb" and "copydb".

All I want to do is to periodically copy realdb to copydb.  The copydb database is our "testing" instance of the actual database "realdb", and we want to periodically update it.

Normally the answer to this question would be "copydb" or "export/import".  However, there are some challenges:

- The target Mongo instance is running version 1.6 and is not likely to be updated anytime soon.
- The target Mongo instance is on a remote server to which I don't have direct access.

This seems like basic enough a function that even 1.6 should have the ability to do it.  But when I try anything I get "No such cmd" errors as if the newer Mongo can't communicate with the ancient Mongo.

Any thoughts on how this could be done?

Comment: What is the exact command that you are running where you're getting "No such cmd"? Can you provide the exact command that you're running and the exact output that you're getting. Copy/paste it here.

Comment: Sorry,  I should have thought to put that in the actual description.  I have tried it 3 ways:
From mongo:
db.copyDatabase("licensing_dev","licensing_dev","remote.server.name");
{
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "listCollections failed: { errmsg: \"no such cmd\", bad cmd: { listCollections: 1, filter: { $or: [ { type: \"collection\" }, { type: { $exists: false } } ] }, cursor: {} }, ok: 0.0 }",
    "code" : 18630,
    "codeName" : "Location18630"
}

Comment: I also tried: 
mongodump --host remote.server.name --port 27017 --db licensing_dev --out /tmp/mongo.js
2017-04-21T08:52:17.110-0700    Failed: error getting collections for database `licensing_dev`: error running `listCollections`. Database: `licensing_dev` Err: no such cmd

Comment: And for completeness I tried:
mongoexport --host remote.server.name:27017 --db licensing_dev --collection seats --out /tmp/mongo.js
2017-04-21T08:55:39.759-0700    Failed: error running `listCollections`. Database: `licensing_dev` Err: no such cmd

Comment: Oddly, I was able to export using rockmongo, but I was unable to import it because of a "file too large" error.  That doesn't really help me, though, because my ultimate objective is to automate the periodic copying of one database to another.

Comment: It's probably obvious, but I should say that the remote instance has no authentication.

Comment: Can you try [db.runCommand()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.runCommand/) using the [copydb](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/command/copydb/) command. db.copyDatabase might not exist in the 1.6 shell.

Comment: use admin
    db.runCommand({
    copydb: 1,
    fromdb: "licensing_dev",
    todb: "licensing_dev",
    fromhost: "remote.server.name"
    })
    {
    "ok" : 0,
    "errmsg" : "listCollections failed: { errmsg: \"no such cmd\", bad cmd: { 
    listCollections: 1, filter: { $or: [ { type: \"collection\" }, { type: { $exists: 
    false } } ] }, cursor: {} }, ok: 0.0 }",
    "code" : 18630,
    "codeName" : "Location18630"
    }

Comment: So that error message looks like the mongo shell that you're running is mismatched with the version of the db server. Can you verify your mongo shell version?

Comment: My local has mongo 3.4.2.  The two are almost definitely far out of sync.  I'm hoping there's some way to get around it.  If there's someplace I can download an ancient version of the mongo shell, that would be an acceptable solution as well.  I couldn't find one.

Comment: Hrm.  Actually I did find this:  https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
And this has an "All Version Binaries" link.  I'll check that out.

Comment: Yep.  Downloaded version 1.6 of mongo to my local and ran its version of mongoexport and mongoimport and it worked great.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you got it working. For completeness and so that we can mark this as answered, I've posted a summary of things to look for in this situation (No such commnand error). I'd appreciate it if you would accept the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Done and done.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error "no such command" might mean that:

1. The command was mistyped, or does not exist
2. There is a mismatch of the client version (e.g. mongo shell, mongodump, mongoexport, or a mongodb driver) and the server version.

In this case it was a mismatch of the mongo shell version (3.4) vs server version (1.6).

Comment: If you find yourself in this situation and you need an older version of Mongo you can find it here:  https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#community
Look for the "All Version Binaries" link on the lower left part of the page.